# Prevent nodejs from minifying javascript code while developing / debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js

NodeJS will minify the javascript code it sends to the browser. Is there a way to prevent this, so it's easier to debug the code in Firebug / Chrome's Inspector?

Comment: node.js doesn't minify anything by default. Which libraries are you using? Provide server initialization code, if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[asset manager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager)

> Merge and minify CSS/javascript files

Your asset manager minifies it for you. So either turn it off or use the express [`configurations`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) to set up a development configuration that doesn't use this middleware